# convert docx into html code in javascript or php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a text editor, and I want to import a docx into this editor,

The js or php will automatically convert docx into html code, and then put the html code into the editor.

I find two package to achieve this, one is [docx2html](https://github.com/lalalic/docx2html), another is [mammoth](https://github.com/mwilliamson/mammoth.js)

but this two package still not working well in my website

```
require("docx2html")(event.target.files[0]).then(function(converted){
　　// console.log(converted)
　　document.querySelector('textarea').value=converted.toString()
})
```

[docx2html](https://github.com/lalalic/docx2html) will show $ is not a function, (because i import many jquery)

so can anyone have some simple function to do that?

only import text is ok to be allowed, style can be not to convert.

Thank you ! :]

Comment: jquery has a no-conflict mode, so that other libraries may use `$` as well

Comment: @LarsStegelitz Should I put var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); in the top of the script?